# ScrollView does not work inside a dynamically created element

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, frameworkelement

I need to create some FrameworkElements dinamically. I have a StackPanel, and I create inside of it a Pivot, with one PivotItem, and inside a ScrollViewer with a StackPanel and Buttons, like this:

```
Pivot pivot = new Pivot();
PivotItem pivotItem = new PivotItem();

pivot.Items.Add(pivotItem);

ScrollViewer scrollViewer = new ScrollViewer();
StackPanel stackContent = new StackPanel();

scrollViewer.Content = stackContent;

pivotItem.Content = scrollViewer;

stackContent.Children.Add(new Button() { Content = "button 1" });
stackContent.Children.Add(new Button() { Content = "button 2" });
stackContent.Children.Add(new Button() { Content = "button 3" });
stackContent.Children.Add(new Button() { Content = "button 4" });
stackContent.Children.Add(new Button() { Content = "button 5" });
stackContent.Children.Add(new Button() { Content = "button 6" });
stackContent.Children.Add(new Button() { Content = "button 7" });
stackContent.Children.Add(new Button() { Content = "button 8" });
stackContent.Children.Add(new Button() { Content = "button 9" });
stackContent.Children.Add(new Button() { Content = "button 10" });
stackContent.Children.Add(new Button() { Content = "button 11" });

stkPanel.Children.Add(pivot);
```

and this is C# XAML code:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="stkPanel">
</StackPanel>
```

If I try to create the all Elements in the XAML, ScrollViewer works as expected, but I need to create them dynamically when some events occurs in page.

Inspecting the page in debug, PivotItem has "ActualHeight == 0", so I suppose ScrollViewer inside it do not works for this reason, but I do not know how to fix it, maybe some way of say to the ScrollViewer "recharge yourself" to make the scroll works.

Comment: Can you maybe add the working code when creating everything in XAML? But basically a StackPanel uses as much space as it requires so a ScrollViewer in a StackPanel should never work if I'm not wrong...

Comment: This is the problem, the damn StackPanel ... If I change it by Grid, all works fine!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the StackPanel. As Schumi1331 said, the stack panel uses as much space as it requires, son never has a define width or height, and scrollViewer does not work as expected. If I change by a Grid, works fine.

Another solution is calculate, after insert dinnamics elements, how much space are using this elements, and setting the height to the StackPanel.

Comment: What's your benefit of putting the Pivot into a StackPanel instead of a Grid?

Comment: in my case, the elements are created dynamically with the response of webService, and has many types like pivot, textbox, etc. So I need a container (Stackpanel or Grid or any other container) to place Elements one below the other, so it's easier place them into Stackpanel than a Grid (in which you need set de row number of each element). Anyway, I have recoded the function to use a Grid, and works fine!

Comment: I see. Maybe using a RelativePanel and the Below-properties would be an option for the next time?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set IsVerticalScrollEnabled to true giving your element a MaxHeight
but a better solution would be a ListView or GridView giving them Max Height attribute after which you want the scrollbar to appear.

```
    <StackPanel x:Name="stkPanel" isVerticalScrollEnabled = "true" MaxHeight="300"> 
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Pivot pivot = new Pivot();
        PivotItem pivotItem = new PivotItem();

        pivot.Items.Add(pivotItem);

        ScrollViewer scrollViewer = new ScrollViewer();
        StackPanel stackContent = new StackPanel();

        scrollViewer.Content = stackContent;
        Window.Current.Activate();
        var bounds = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().VisibleBounds;
        scrollViewer.Height = bounds.Height;
        pivotItem.Content = scrollViewer;

        stackContent.Children.Add(new Button() { Content = "button 1" });
        stackContent.Children.Add(new Button() { Content = "button 2" });
        stackContent.Children.Add(new Button() { Content = "button 3" });
        stackContent.Children.Add(new Button() { Content = "button 4" });
        stackContent.Children.Add(new Button() { Content = "button 5" });
        stackContent.Children.Add(new Button() { Content = "button 6" });
        stackContent.Children.Add(new Button() { Content = "button 7" });
        stackContent.Children.Add(new Button() { Content = "button 8" });
        stackContent.Children.Add(new Button() { Content = "button 9" });
        stackContent.Children.Add(new Button() { Content = "button 10" });
        stackContent.Children.Add(new Button() { Content = "button 11" });

        stkPanel.Children.Add(pivot);
```

Comment: Have you tested this solution? I did, but seems not works :( As I said in previus commets, it seems that it has relation with the stackpanels